# Executing PHP script on Azure using Arduino

Tags: php, azure, arduino

I'm attempting to move a project from my web hosting service to an Azure Web Application.  The Arduino code works perfectly when configured for my hosting, however, when I change the host to my Azure domain it no longer works... the files are all there correct places and the 'insert.php' script works perfectly when i input the value manually.  I have a suspicion that Azure might be blocking the connection from the Arduino.?   Please see code below.

Arduino code snippet

```
void sendDataToServer(String boardID, int L_P_G, int CARBON, int SULPHUR, String LAT,String LONG)
{
  Serial.println("uploading to server");

  if (client.connect(servername, 80)) { // starts client connection, checks for connection
    Serial.println("Sending data to MYSql");
    client.println("GET /insert.php?boardID=" + boardID + "&L_P_G=" + L_P_G + "&CARBON=" + CARBON + "&SULPHUR=" + SULPHUR + "&lat=" + LAT +  "&lng=" + LONG +" HTTP/1.1"); //Send data
    client.println("Host: xxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net");
    // client.println("Host: xxxxxxxxx.xx");
    client.println("Connection: close");  // close 1.1 persistent connection
    client.println(); // end of get request
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed"); // error message if no client connect
    Serial.println();
  }

  client.stop(); // stop client
}
```

Comment: See if you request makes it through, turn on web server logs in [Diagnostic Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/media/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/logspart.png) under your web app in Azure.

Comment: You may also want to [print the HTTP response](https://github.com/snobu/the-italian-webjob/blob/master/ConsumeIoTHubFromMega.ino#L87-L102), maybe you are getting one but it's not a 200 OK.